# Strip shortcode from excerpt

Tags: plugins, filters, shortcode, tags

I have this challenge, that i've found out that i'm not the only one in the WEB with the same issue, nevertheless, there are no solutions yet.

I'm trying to remove shortcodes from my custom post types excerpts.

here is my example:
http://guidepaperback.com/city/new-century-hotel/

in sidebar there's the "in the neighborhood" widget that shows images with excerpts... some are showing this issue.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A simple [search in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes) and you can set this! Anyway you can do something like :

```
function remove_shortcode_from_excerpt($content) {
  $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
  return $content;//always return $content
  }
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'remove_shortcode_from_excerpt');
```

Comment: Thank for brief reply!
But seems that doesn't work. I've inserted that code in the functions child theme... but with no results.
Am i missing somenthing?

Comment: Check to see if the code is running. Before the `return $content;` line add this: `wp_die( '<pre>In ' . __function__ . '()</pre>' );`. If the function is running, that should break the web site and display `In remove_shortcode_from_excerpt()`.

Comment: Once again... it's not working! 
This is what i have for excerpt inside theme custom functions:

if (!function_exists('excerpt')) {
function excerpt($limit=10) {
  $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(),$limit);
  if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
  } else {
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
  } 
  $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
  return $excerpt;
}}

Does this help in any way?

Comment: means you already have an excerpt function that could be the reason you can't make it work.

Comment: Can i change this function in the child theme?

Comment: Yes because there's a `if(!functions_exists(''))` in parent `functions.php` and the child `functions.php` is always loaded before so to override just use `function excerpt() { }` in your child theme.